# Pointers and virtual memory

Tags: c, linux, pointers, ubuntu, memory

According to my system's cpuinfo file, each processor in my system has a 39 bit physical address size and a 48 bit virtual address size.

My system has 16 GB of ram, so the 39 bit physical address size makes sense to me as 39 bits is more than enough to address 16GB of ram.

However, the 48 bit virtual address size confuses me. I always believed that I could write C programs that, from the source code's perspective, could address 2^64 bytes of virtual memory (as a pointer on my system is 8 bytes long according to size(void *)). However, cpuinfo is telling me that I only have 2^48 bytes of virtual memory. So does that mean my C program can only address 2^48 bytes of virtual memory?

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: i want to know what the relationship between cpuinfo's virtual address size  and my system being "nominally" 64 bit is.

Comment: One of the uses of higher-level languages (even though C is pretty low in the low-high scale) is to abstract away the hardware. In C you have a pointer. It points to "memory". That's really all you need to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your 64-bit system, pointers are indeed 64 bit wide. That means, there's 2<sup>64</sup> possible values for a pointer.

However, [current x86-64 (AMD64) implementations](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/24593_APM_v2.pdf) only use the lower 48 bits. That means only 2<sup>48</sup> actually potentially valid pointers and quite a lot of pointers which are always invalid.

[AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 2: System Programming](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/24593_APM_v2.pdf) states:

> Currently, the AMD64 architecture defines a mechanism for translating 48-bit virtual addresses to 52- bit physical addresses. The mechanism used to translate a full 64-bit virtual address is reserved and will be described in a future AMD64 architectural specification.

Comment: I suspected that if i tried to address memory that fell outside of the 48 bit range, i would get a segfault (but i could never be sure that this segfault was caused by the 48 bit issue as other events can trigger it). Thank you for confirming what i suspected.

Comment: Actually, none of the built-in variables is required to use all bits of the used bitwidth (`(sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT`). Also some bits can be used for other purposes than the address, e.g. they could encode the type.

Comment: @josh Unless you start writing assembler code or using hard-coded addresses for pointers, or of course use uninitialized pointer variables, then you will never get an illegal address. The compiler and the library and the operating system will simply not give you an illegal address.

Answer (score 2):

The development of new CPU's for faster and more powerful execution pushed for the extension of the machine registry, what is normally called the machine word.
The grow of internal data registers, started on earlier CPU's from 4bits (4004), through 8, 16, 32, 64 up to 128bits (Alpha), and maybe more in the future.
Standard processors, the main class of them as the more diffused defined as general computing, have as one of the main characteristic the size equivalence of the Instruction Pointer register, and consequently the addressing range, with the machine natural word. So on a 64bits CPU the IP, and so the memory addresses, where extended to 64bits.
But 64bits of addressing are really a huge addressing range, up to 18.446.744.073.709.551.616 bytes (16.777.216Tbytes). Something simply unfeasible with current technologies. For this reason they decided to limit the real addressing to 1Tbyte (2^40). This choice reduced CPU complexity and its power consumption.
With same aim to limit MMU registers (Memory Management Unit registers) and memory used for page directory decided to limit virtual memory to 256Tbyte (2^48).
Consider that extending memory addressing lines made more complex even the memory address decoding, requiring more logic gates, that in turn would require more power and slows down decoding timings, and then the memory access cycles.
On actual system each address, virtual or physical, having last 16 bits set triggers a memory access exception.
In conclusion 64bits can be beneficial on general computation, but are not effective in addressing, but **`memory pointer size = machine natural integer size`** is still desirable, so...